# Is there an equivalent to intptr_t and uintptr_t in CUDA

Tags: c++, types, cuda, atomic

Since `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` refer to integer types capable of holding a *host* pointer, is there some equivalent that can be used in device code?

This would be particularly useful for device-side atomics, since the atomic functions don't accept pointers to pointer types, and thus a conversion is required (to whatever the equivalent of `uintptr_t *` is). Is it safe to assume that device pointers are 64 bits wide, and use `unsigned long long *`?

While googling, I've seen some mentions of a `CUdeviceptr` type, which sounds like it might be the equivalent of `intptr_t`, but can't find much discussion or documentation for what it is or how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: CUDA adheres to C++.  AFAIK these types are not defined in C++, but if you `#include <cstdint>` you will have access to them, including in CUDA device code.  Regarding this: "Since intptr_t and uintptr_t refer to integer types capable of holding a host pointer,"  with respect to the usage of the word *host*, I think that is your invention.  I doubt any description of those types includes the word *host*.  I also don't understand their utility with respect to atomics, or under what circumstances using pointer-to-pointer types would be interesting with atomics, but that seems tangential.

Comment: regarding the width of pointers on the device, they always match the width of pointers on the host.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: The descriptions of `std::intptr_t` and `std::uintptr_t` know nothing about CUDA or GPUs, so of course they are concerned with the host pointer size (it's the only kind of pointer they know about).

Comment: @RobertCrovella do you have a reference that states that device and host pointers always have the same width? This seems to indicate otherwise: https://www.cudahandbook.com/2013/08/why-does-cuda-cudeviceptr-use-unsigned-int-instead-of-void/, and this question about OpenCL also says the same thing about pointer sizes in OpenCL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302831/size-of-pointer-on-gpu-vs-size-of-pointer-on-cpu

Comment: [1](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#bit-compatibility)  [2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#machine-64-m)

Comment: @BenVoigt you're imagining a distinction where it doesn't exist.  CUDA device code also claims compatibility to C++.  The point of that claim is that there is no need to restate, assume, or declare that every C++ specification is now unique to host only, and has a host word implicitly added in it somewhere, with a corresponding additional specification necessary to state the same thing for device.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Ok, thanks. If you want to put that as an answer, (something like "uintptr_t and intptr_t can safely be used in device code because host and device pointers always have the same width"), I can accept that.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, then, if you think it depends on pointer width.  In device code, the pointer width doesn't vary (just like it doesn't in C++). There are not, format-wise, different kinds of pointers (just like there aren't, in C++). The requested types are utilizable with an appropriate include (or converting to the `std::` equivalent type), without any further stipulations (just the same as in C++). Again, this is based on CUDA device code having a stated claim of adherence to C++. Your question (and suggested answer) starts with a false premise. I can't address it.

Answer (score 1):

> While googling, I've seen some mentions of a CUdeviceptr type, which sounds like it might be the equivalent of `intptr_t`, but can't find much discussion or documentation for what it is or how it is supposed to be used.

`CUdeviceptr` is indeed quite similar to `intptr_t`, except that it is not associated with `int`'s in particular. CUDA driver API functions typically don't take nor return regular pointers, but rather - `CUdeviceptr`'s, containing a address, valid on the device, as a number.

> Since `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` refer to integer types capable of holding a host pointer, is there some equivalent that can be used in device code?

I'm guessing you're trying to do something which you shouldn't...

> This would be particularly useful for device-side atomics, since the atomic functions don't accept pointers to pointer types, and thus a conversion is required (to whatever the equivalent of uintptr_t * is).

That's an issue not just for pointers - but for any types other than the ones which have specific atomic API functions. So, do like we all do: reinterpret-cast...

Better yet - don't do this yourself, use either:

- NVIDIA's 20-pound-hammer solution: [cuda::std::atomic](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/extended_api/synchronization_primitives/atomic.html), part of their CUDA Standard(ish) C++ library; or
- My [atomic operation wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/blob/master/src/kat/on_device/atomics.cuh) within my cuda-kat library:

  ```
  template <typename T>  KAT_FD T add        (T* address, T val);
  template <typename T>  KAT_FD T subtract   (T* address, T val);
  template <typename T>  KAT_FD T exchange   (T* address, T val);
  template <typename T>  KAT_FD T min        (T* address, T val);
  template <typename T>  KAT_FD T max        (T* address, T val);
  template <typename T>  KAT_FD T logical_and(T* address, T val);
  template <typename T>  KAT_FD T logical_or (T* address, T val);
  // etc. etc.
  ```

  which takes care of it for you. No `CUdeviceptr` required.

> Is it safe to assume that device pointers are 64 bits wide, and use unsigned long long *?

Well, maybe so, maybe no; but you don't need to make that assumption. `sizeof()` is your friend (that's what I use); or you could check at build configuration time (CMake, for example, provides a `check_type_size()` command).